# How to append data from a certain column to one cell?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data set. Only the data in the "internalnotes" needs to be in one cell. All the other data is the same for a CaseNumber, except the "internalnotes". The CaseNumber column is not the index for my data.

How can I append all the data in the "internalnotes" for a specific CaseNumber in one cell?

[image]

Comment: Please can you paste `ans_new.head().to_dict()`. Images can't be copied and pasted usefully. Please also read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is one way. `groupby.apply(list)` will aggregate all the `internalnotes` per group into a list.

```
group_cols = ['CaseNumber', 'ProcessInstanceDescription', 'ProdOpsCaseOwner',
              'personname', 'SNLAnalystEntryDesc']

ans_new = ans_new.groupby(group_cols)['internalnotes'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

If you really want to join strings, as @jezrael suggests, and remove all knowledge of the fact the values came from different rows:

```
ans_new = ans_new.groupby(group_cols)['internalnotes'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: `.apply(list)` ? I think `.apply(' '.join)`

Comment: That's one option @jezrael :), I'm making a suggestion which user might realise makes more sense.